# SwiftUI error: Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello I am trying to create a messaging app and I would like to add a header of the date or day for each group of messages. When I try to append to the array in the viewModel I get the error "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." I tried wrapping this in a Dispatch.main.async but that did not work, does anyone know a fix, thanks.

view

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
struct MessagesView: View {
    let messages: [Message]
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MessageViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
               LazyVStack(spacing: 3){ 
                   ForEach(messages){ message in
                       if let dateStr = viewModel.getDate(date: message.timestamp) {
                             Text(dateStr)
                       }
                       MessageBubble(message: message)
                   }                               
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

viewModel

```
import Foundation
class MessageViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var dayArr = [String]()  

    func getDate(date: Timestamp) -> String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

        let val = date.dateValue()
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: val)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)!
        let dateToCompare = calendar.startOfDay(for: val)

        if dateToCompare == today {
            if !dayArr.contains("Today"){
                dayArr.append("Today") //error here when trying to append
                return "Today"
            } else{
                return nil
            }
        } else if dateToCompare == yesterday {
            if !dayArr.contains("Yesterday"){
                dayArr.append("Yesterday") //error here when trying to append
                return "Yesterday"
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            if !dayArr.contains(dateString){
                dayArr.append(dateString) //error here when trying to append
                return dateString 
            } else{
                return nil
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: you are calling `getDate` when the body is reloading and changing variables. the `body` should not do work

Comment: @loremipsum what should I do to fix it? do you have a workaround possibly

Comment: Call the method in an action such as `onAppear` or `task` or on `init` of the VM and hold the result in a variable. You have a view model, why do work in a view? You can put the string in the message too. Find somewhere else to do it, the `body` is for displaying results and receiving user input, it shouldn't be triggering work.

Comment: @loremipsum I updated the code and tried to use the function in the viewModel, still won't work. I also tried to put the getDate code inside of a onRecieve(message) block inside of the forEach loop but that didn't work. also I can't just store the result in a variable because I will have multiple results because different messages may be in different days. So storing it in a variable would cause  an overwrite. Can you possibly show me an example of what I can do please.

Comment: Is `dayArr` an array of unique dates?

Comment: @loremipsum yes it is. It contains strings like "today", "yesterday", "4/20/2023", and so on. I store each unique date inside of it once. I do something like "!dayArr.contains("Yesterday"){" to ensure that each group of messages only has one date header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each `Message` is going to have its own `getDate` the method should be inside the `Message`.

```
struct Message: Identifiable{
    let id: UUID = .init()
    let timestamp: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: (-10...10).randomElement()!, to: Date())! //Using Date instead of Timestamp, you can change the type
    var getDate : String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

        let val = self.timestamp//.dateValue() //Adjust the type back to Timestamp
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: val)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)!
        let dateToCompare = calendar.startOfDay(for: val)

        if dateToCompare == today {
            return "Today"
        } else if dateToCompare == yesterday {
            return "Yesterday"
        } else {
            return dateString

        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `View` you can use `map` and `Set` to get the values together and make a unique Sequence.

```
import SwiftUI
struct MessagesView: View {
    let messages: [Message] = (1...50).map { _ in
            .init()
    }//Sample data
    @StateObject var viewModel: MessageViewModel = .init() //Can leave as EnvironmentObject in your project, change to StateObject for a sample
    
    var dayArr : Set<String> { //Set automatically removes duplicates
        Set(messages.map { m in
            m.getDate
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
               LazyVStack(spacing: 3){
                   ForEach(messages){ message in
                       Text(message.getDate)
                       
                       //MessageBubble(message: message)
                   }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            viewModel.dayArr = Array(dayArr) //Only if you need this
        }
    }
}
```

With this method you can also group your messages with a dictionary.

```
    var dayGroups: [String: [Message]]{ //Group by getDate
        Dictionary(grouping: messages, by: \.getDate)
    }
```

Then you can let swift to all the work and just use it to display without any other conditionals.

```
import SwiftUI
struct MessagesView: View {
    let messages: [Message] = (1...50).map { _ in
            .init()
    }//Sample data
    @StateObject var viewModel: MessageViewModel = .init() //Can leave as EnvironmentObject in your project, change to StateObject for a sample
    
    var dayGroups: [String: [Message]]{ //Group by getDate
        Dictionary(grouping: messages, by: \.getDate)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(Array(dayGroups), id:\.key){ (date, messages) in
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        LazyVStack(spacing: 3){
                            ForEach(messages){ message in
                                Text(message.getDate)
                                
                                //MessageBubble(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(date)\t\t\(messages.count.description)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DateFormatter() is expensive — better to have a static instance